# Deep neural network training on large datasets

Tags: neural-networks

I am training a deep net on large training dataset. I read the tutorial from the following link:
[Training on Large Datasets](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksLargeDatasets.html). 
I have put each predictor-preditand tuple into a separate mx file.
My question is, since my input data is not image, how can I encode the file, so that NetTrain[net,{File[…]->…,…},…] can automatically does out-of-core learning on the dataset where File[…] represents my training data?
Thanks!

Comment: I think that the easiest way to go, is to use a generator function as explained in the section "Training with a Generator Function" on that page. Just adjust the function to import the data from the files with `Import` or `Get`. I'm guessing that the `File[...] -> out` format is optimized only for images.

Comment: Thanks Sjoered, "Input"->NetEncoder[{"Function",Import,dimension}]]] works for the NetEncoder. A following question is, can I have similar import function for the output, using NetDecoder?

Comment: You can just specify the generator function in the 2nd argument of `NetTrain` such that each evaluation of the function yields a batch of training examples (both input and output). That's probably the easiest. I don't know if you can do it through `NetDecoder`.

Comment: I tried  NetTrain[net,Map[#[[1]]->Import[#[[2]]]&,data]], where data are in the format of  {File[]->File[]}, it is working now. Thank you so much!